# VerQueryValue in Windows10

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I have moved from `Win8` to `Win10` with my `VS2012 C++` project. I had no problem while using `VerQueryValue` function in Win8, but now I have error during debug:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77C88F11 (ntdll.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00AAC2DC.
```

I use sample code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
CString GetVersionInfo(HMODULE hLib, CString csEntry)
{
    CString csRet;

    if (hLib == NULL)
        hLib = AfxGetResourceHandle();

    HRSRC hVersion = FindResource( hLib, 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(VS_VERSION_INFO), RT_VERSION );
    if (hVersion != NULL)
    {
        HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource( hLib, hVersion ); 
        if ( hGlobal != NULL)  
        {  

            LPVOID versionInfo  = LockResource(hGlobal);  
            if (versionInfo != NULL)
            {
                DWORD vLen,langD;
                BOOL retVal;    

                LPVOID retbuf=NULL;

                static char fileEntry[256];

                sprintf(fileEntry,"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation");
                retVal = VerQueryValue(versionInfo,fileEntry,&retbuf,(UINT *)&vLen);
                if (retVal && vLen==4) 
                {
                    memcpy(&langD,retbuf,4);            
                    sprintf(fileEntry, "\\StringFileInfo\\%02X%02X%02X%02X\\%s",
                        (langD & 0xff00)>>8,langD & 0xff,(langD & 0xff000000)>>24, 
                        (langD & 0xff0000)>>16, csEntry);            
                }
                else 
                    sprintf(fileEntry, "\\StringFileInfo\\%04X04B0\\%s", 
                    GetUserDefaultLangID(), csEntry);

                if (VerQueryValue(versionInfo,fileEntry,&retbuf,(UINT *)&vLen)) 
                    csRet = (char*)retbuf;
            }
        }

        UnlockResource( hGlobal );  
        FreeResource( hGlobal );  
    }

    return csRet;
}
```

What might be problem?

Comment: Do some debugging. Which particular memory write in your code results in the exception. An aside. Why did you decide to make `fileEntry` static? You know that means your function is not threadsafe? What could possibly be gained by making it static?

Comment: exception exactly in `VerQueryValue` ? or may be in `sprintf` when you using `%s` with `CString csEntry` ?

Comment: Show the call stack. Show how you call `GetVersionInfo`. Show a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

You are *directly* accessing the version resource data instead of using `GetFileVersionInfo()`.  As such, you **cannot** use `VerQueryValue()` to query localized values, you can query **only** the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` structure and nothing else.  And even then, you cannot use the return value of `LockResource()` for that access, either.  You **must** copy the resource data into your own read/write memory buffer before then accessing the structure.

The reason for this is because `GetFileVersionInfo()` performs data lookups and memory block allocations that `VerQueryValue()` uses internally.  Raymond Chen explains this on his blog:

[The first parameter to VerQueryValue really must be a buffer you obtained from GetFileVersionInfo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061226-06/?p=28603)

> The documentation says that the first parameter to VerQueryValue must be a buffer returned by the GetFileVersionInfo function for a reason. **The buffer returned by GetFileVersionInfo is an opaque data block specifically formatted so that VerQueryValue will work**. You're not supposed to look inside that buffer, and you certainly can't try to "obtain the data some other way". Because **if you do, VerQueryValue will look for something in a buffer that is not formatted in the manner the function expects**.

That is why you are getting a crash - `VerQueryValue()` is trying to access memory that has not been setup properly.

If you are going to access the version resource directly, then you need to parse its data manually, do not use `VerQueryValue()` at all.  You were *lucky* that your code never crashed before.  You were operating in **undefined behavior** territory!  Your luck has run out.  You need to re-write the code to do the right thing.